# Как обнаружить изменения в переменной?

Tags: c++, qt

Допустим в одном классе у меня есть элемент QLineEdit, а в другом классе QString value. Как сделать так, чтобы текст в QLineEdit автоматически изменялся при любом изменении значения  QString value?

Comment: У класса QString нет сигналов. Поэтому потребуется самостоятельно реализовать класс-обёртку, содержащую QString, в этом классе создать сигнал onChanged и при обработке этого сигнала вставлять новый текст в QLineEdit.

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Привык к C#, где есть OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Про автоматическое изменение будьте аккуратны, один из столпов ООП подразумевает, что любая сущность может изменять только своё состояние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связать изменение состояния `QLineEdit` с событием, по которому изменяется значение в переменной типа `QString`.
Вообще говоря при программировании GUI есть концепция хранения значения переменной в графической части, т.е. использовать `lineEdit->text()` непосредственно вместо переменной типа `QString`. Иначе будут проблемы при изменении текста в `QLineEdit` пользователем - нужно будет связывать их и в обратном направлении.

Comment: До сих пор у меня такая реализация. QLineEdit использую вместо QString. Пока лучше варианта нет.